# Need help in Avalara Integration

Tags: acumatica, avalara

We have integrated Avalara Tax Integration for tax calculations in Sales Order screens, how we can override the address which Acumatica is passing to Avalara with our custom address, I mean right now it is passing Shipping address I need to pass Billing Address.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  Although I am certified in Acumatica and have integrated Avalara with it, admittedly, I tend to focus on the business process more than the developing side.

Technically, I am not sure how to achieve what you asked since the Acumatica Avalara connector uses the shipping address by default.  I have two suggestions:

One, you might open a ticket with Acumatica to discuss a potential change to the connector.  For example, add a drop-box SHIPPING / BILLING field and depending on which option is selected at the connector will go left or right.

Two, input the Bill To address in the Ship To Address fields.  Then, create a second set of Ship To Address fields (using custom fields - i.e, "Destination") that will be used throughout the system for where the order is actually shipping to.  Of course, the trade-off here is that you need to customize ship to address on forms and reports wherever else you need it.

Good luck!

Dru